# How to type the zod schema object based on a predefined type?

Tags: typescript, zod

I have the following code:

```
class MyModel {
  propA: string
  propB: number
  propC: boolean
  constructor() {
    this.propA = ''
    this.propB = 123
    this.propC = true
  }
}
```

I want to create a Zod schema object based on this class, so that the **keys** and the **values** will correspond to this type:

```
const mySchema = z.object<SOME_GENERIC_METHOD_HERE<MyModel>>({
propA: z.string(),
  propB: z.number(),
  propC: z
    .boolean()
    .optional()
    .transform((i) => i),
})
})
```

I have tried to create a simple generic function that worked perfectly when `strictNullChecks` option in the **tsconfig.json** is disabled:

```
type ZodSchemaKeysFrom1<E> = {
  [k in keyof E]: ZodType<E[k]>
}

const mySchema = z.object<ZodSchemaKeysFrom1<MyModel>>({
  propA: z.string(),
  propB: z.number(),
  propC: z
    .boolean()
    .optional()
    .transform((i) => i),
})

type MySchemaFields = z.infer<typeof mySchema>
```

In this case `MySchemaFields` type is being inferred correctly as:

```
type MySchemaFields = {
    propA?: string;
    propB?: number;
    propC?: boolean;
}
```

It's the same type that will be inferred if you remove the generic angle brackets from `z.object<xxx>()`

Now, the problem is, I don't want to disable this typescript flag, I want my code to be as  strict as possible to avoid future mistakes.

So when I remove this flag (`strictNullChecks`), I get the following error only on the propC in the zod schema:

[image]

The error messsage is:

```
Type 'ZodEffects<ZodOptional<ZodBoolean>, boolean | undefined, boolean | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'ZodType<boolean, ZodTypeDef, boolean>'.
  Types of property '_type' are incompatible.
    Type 'boolean | undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.ts(2322)
index.ts(6, 3): The expected type comes from property 'propC' which is declared here on type 'ZodSchemaKeysFrom1<MyModel>'

(property) propC: ZodType<boolean, z.ZodTypeDef, boolean>
```

How can I avoid this error?

I have created a code sandbox for everyone to try it out.

[Click here to see and try it in my devbox codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/zod-keys-schema-9krk5v?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.ts)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete solution because you have to write a new type, but it might point you in the right direction.

typescript

```
type MyObject = {
  field: ZodString;
};

const schema = z.object<MyObject>({ field: z.string() });
```

**EDIT:**
Check out this [issue](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/discussions/1928) on GitHub, it has a utility type to perform this conversion. Like this:

```js
type MyObject = {
  field: string;
};

export type Equals<X, Y> = (<T>() => T extends X ? 1 : 2) extends <
  T,
>() => T extends Y ? 1 : 2
  ? true
  : false;

type NonUndefined<T> = Exclude<T, undefined>;

export type ZodInferSchema<T extends object> = {
  [Key in keyof T]-?: Equals<T[Key], NonUndefined<T[Key]>> extends false
    ?
        | z.ZodOptional<z.ZodType<NonNullable<T[Key]>>>
        | z.ZodPipeline<z.ZodOptional<z.ZodType<any>>, z.ZodType<T[Key]>>
    : z.ZodType<T[Key]> | z.ZodPipeline<z.ZodType<any>, z.ZodType<T[Key]>>;
};

type MyZodObject = ZodInferSchema<MyObject>;

const schema = z.object<MyZodObject>({ field: z.string() });
```

Comment: Ok, I see, then it looks like there's no other solution without having to create a big union, I created one based on my needs, I will find a better way maybe later

Comment: ok, according to the first code block, if I wanted ot make `field` optional inside the `MyObject`, but required in the schema (ie, no `.optional()`), then how?

Comment: I have tried the following `type MyObject = {
  field?: ZodString;
};
`

Comment: and it works but then when I do the `z.infer<schema>` I get the keys but the values for the optional ones are `unknown`

Answer (score -1):

I solved this complex problem as follows:

I created this type (myself)

```
export type ZodSchemaKeysFrom<E> = {
  [k in keyof E]:
    | ZodType<E[k]>
    | ZodDefault<ZodType<E[k]>>
    | ZodEffects<ZodDefault<ZodType<E[k]>>>
    | ZodOptional<ZodEffects<ZodDefault<ZodType<E[k]>>>>
    | ZodOptional<ZodType<E[k]>>
    | ZodDefault<ZodOptional<ZodType<E[k]>>>
    | ZodEffects<ZodOptional<ZodType<E[k]>>>
}
```

> Note: this type is most likely incomplete, so if you're going to copy/paste it, it might work on most of your schema fields, but fields will trigger a compile time error, so in that case, what you're going to do, is to add more union members to this type based on your needs, (how? in the error message, you'll see that `X` is not assignable to ZodSchemaKeysFrom...etc error, just append the `X` type into this big union - and for every type missing).

And then, in the schema, instead of using the generic argument provided by the `z.object()` method, I used the typescript `satisfies` keyword to typecheck my schema object, and let the auto inference auto infer everything for me:

```
const mySchema = z.object({
  propA: z.string(),
  propB: z.number(),
  propC: z
    .boolean()
    .optional()
    .transform((i) => i),
} satisfies ZodSchemaKeysFrom<MyModel>)

type MySchemaFields = z.infer<typeof mySchema>
```

Using the `satisfies` keyword allowed me to also make some of the `MyModel` field optional in the mySchema object by using `Partial<>` without losing the type inference for the values inside the `MySchemaFields` (the `z.infer<>`).

For example:

```
type MySchema = ZodSchemaKeysFrom<Partial<MyModel>> & ZodSchemaKeysFrom<{passwordConfirm: string}>

const mySchema = z.object({
 // ...etc
 passwordConfirm: z.string()
} satisfies MySchema)
```

I hope this solution will help someone in the future.